# Python: Slow/delayed execution of external program when started from script using an eventloop [Windows]

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, subprocess, pyside

I have encountered a very strange problem with executing external programs with python under Windows. I have been trying to find out whats going on for multiple weeks now and I am completely out of ideas.

## Problem

If I run my `tool.exe` in the context of an GUI application with some workload right after `tool.exe` is called, the startup of the `tool.exe` is delayed. The window shows but is frozen and becomes responsive only after either the workload finishes or 15 to 30 seconds passed.

## Code

I have attached 3 versions of my code for both `Tk` & `PySide2`. Both GUI toolkits show the same behaviour.

#### Tk Example

```
##### Version 1 #####
import subprocess, tkinter, time
subprocess.Popen('tool.exe')
time.sleep(60)


##### Version 2 #####
import subprocess, tkinter, time
tkinter.Tk()
subprocess.Popen('tool.exe')


##### Version 3 #####
import subprocess, tkinter, time
tkinter.Tk()
subprocess.Popen('tool.exe')
time.sleep(60)
```

#### PySide2 Example

```js
##### Version 1 #####
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import subprocess
import time

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        subprocess.Popen('tool.exe')
        time.sleep(60)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
button = Button()
button.show()
app.exec_()


##### Version 2 #####
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import subprocess
import time

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        subprocess.Popen('tool.exe')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
button = Button()
button.show()
app.exec_()


##### Version 3 #####
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import subprocess
import time

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        subprocess.Popen('tool.exe')
        time.sleep(60)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
button = Button()
button.show()
app.exec_()
```

## Result

Version 1: `tool.exe` becomes responsive immediatly

Version 2: `tool.exe` becomes responsive immediatly

Version 3: `tool.exe` becomes responsive after 15-30 seconds (or after the `sleep` is finished when I reduce the sleep time)

## Question

Hopefully somebody can hint me in the right direction to why this behavious is caused. My skript is used dozens of times every day, so this delay is quite a pain. Maybe I could find a dirty hack for my problem, but I'd rather understand what's going on.

#### Finally

- I wasn't able to find a tool that shows similar behaviour. The tool is an old proprietary/commercial tool for Windows with some strange licensing policy. So probably the hardware configuration gets checked when the tool starts up.
- I have tried running the `tool.exe` via `subprocess.Popen`, `os.startfile` and with a batch file. Under new installations of Windows 7 and Windows 10. Using the creationflags `DETACHED_PROCESS` and/or `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, `close_fds=False/True`. It doesn't matter, the problem persists.

#### Update

- I have tried starting the `tool.exe` via `threading` and `multiprocessing`. Doesn't help.
- [Refering to PySide Example] **Whenever I return to the main event loop after starting `tool.exe`, it becomes responsive immediatly.** So yes, using `threading` and `multiprocessing` is possible for the workload if I don't wait for them finishing!

#### Update 2

- I kinda solved my problem by frequently executing `QCoreApplication.processEvents()` in my workload (illustrated by `sleep(60)` above). Still, when I ignore all the occuring events, the `tool.exe` loads just fine. So the secret remains...

Comment: Have you tried `threading` your heavy workload?

Comment: yes, see my updated answer